# how can I Reload ALL Entities (Entries) in my DbSet (not ONE entry)?

Tags: entity-framework, reload, dbcontext, dbset

how can I Reload **ALL** Entities (Entries) in my DbSet (not **ONE** entry)?

i have 2tables:

```
Tbl1 (Id, Name, Tel,...)
Tbl2 (Id, Address, DetailInfo,... )
```

and 1 view:

```
MyView1 (Tb1.Id , Name,Tel , Address , DetailInfo,...)
```

I set DbSet.ToList() in the grid's datasource with my RefreshInfo() function, I edit one Tb1 entity and then call myDbContext.SaveChanges() , it changes in the database, and MyView1 shows correct values **there** , but when I call RefreshInfo() again, it doesnt show values from database!
I can Reload current Entity and it worked , but I want to **Reload all entities** in my DbSet

I want to get fresh data from db everytime i call my RefreshInfo() method.
(I checked with SqlProfiler and I saw ef sent SELECT command to the db, but what happened in return?!)

I dont want to create new dbContext everytime, it's not a good solution
*i'm working with datagridview and entity framework codefirst in winform.*